# Loadrunner 12 TruClient

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner, truclient

I've been using Loadrunner for quite a while mainly with the web/http protocol.  Our Web application is becoming more Ajaxified so after upgrading to loadrunner 12 I thought I'd give the truclient mode a go but am having issues getting the most basic test to replay.

I create a logon action which navigates to the website and signs in.  I put this in the Init Block.  I then create a new action for some business process and put this in the Run Block.  When replaying, the init block runs fine but before it starts my run block the page returns to "about:blank".  Therefore my run action fails as no objects can be found.  Surely the page should remain as per the last navigation?

This can be easily recreated using other sites site bbc.co.uk i.e. Navigate to www.bbc.co.uk in the init and then click some links and put this in the Run block. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for your issue:

1) If you are using "new user simulation" (Runtime Settings -> Replay uncheck "Simulate a new user for each iteration" (first option))

If you don't want to do (1) then:

2) Put the login into the action.

When "Simulate a new user for each iteration" is checked then we cut all the connection between iterations but since init happens only once, before the iterations, we do it after the init.

Comment: Thanks Buzzy.  The problem was indeed option 1.